# Seeding ServiceStack database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In .net core projects I do my seeding inside the Program.cs file like this:

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        //.. do seeding
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

host.Run();
```

In service stack are the services registered in same place?  I tried the code below but `var db = context.OpenDbConnection()` throws exception that service is not registered:

> No service for type 'ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory' has been registered.

This is how I call it:

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionFactory>();


        using (var db = context.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            if(!db.Select<Register>(x => x.Email == "test@example").Any())
            {
                db.Insert(new Register
                {
                    Email = "test@example.com",
                    Password = "1234"
                });
            }

        }

        //.. do seeding
    }
    catch
    {

    }

 }

host.Run();
```

This is how I register it in Startup.cs Configure()

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(_sqliteFileDb, SqliteDialect.Provider));

container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

What is right way for me to register and retrieve the database context?

Comment: What does silent error mean? Please include the full Exception StackTrace that's thrown, if there wasn't any you should be able to debug what's actually happening.

Comment: there is no exception.  Just any break points i put after context.OpenDbConnection() dont get hit.  I cant get an exception message.  So by silent I mean I have no indication of the error other than my breakpoints do not trigger after the method call.

Comment: Are you debugging in **Debug** mode? It's going to either throw an Exception or let you step through and debug each line.

Comment: @mythz sorry you were right I updated my question with the Exception message.  I think I am looking for interface in wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for dependencies in .NET Core's IOC but dependencies [registered in ServiceStack's IOC is only visible to ServiceStack](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter).

Normally you would just seed the data after registering the dependency since they're both only registered and configured once on Startup, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(_sqliteFileDb, SqliteDialect.Provider));

using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
{
    SeedData(db);
}
```

Otherwise you can access dependencies in ServiceStack's IOC with:

```
var dbFactory = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();

using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks mythz, really great support! :)